# Fiori launchpad fails to load UI5 app because it cannot find registered custom module

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I've a custom control in my app. It runs as a standalone web application fine. But when I'm launching it from the Fiori Launchpad (FLP), it logs an error in the console. I've registered my control in my `index.html` file:

```html
<script>
  sap.ui.localResources("sap.custom");
  sap.ui.localResources("sap.ui.codetools");
  sap.ui.localResources("libs");
</script>
```

[image: Error]

The structure of file directory is:

[image: Directory Structure]

If I remove my custom control, then I can run my app in the launchpad. Do I need to add some settings in my manifest file? What could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common configuration for a Fiori tile is to point to the Component file. So the `index.html` file is **not** deployed together with the app. If it's absolutely necessary to register additional module paths, do it in `manifest.json` instead.

```json
{
  "sap.ui5": {
    "resourceRoots": {
      "sap.ui.codetools": "sap/ui/codetools"
    }
  }
}
```

Documentation: [Descriptor for Applications, Components, and Libraries](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da.html#loiobe0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da/section_sap_ui5) (See `resourceRoots`).

Answer (score 0):

The common configuration for a Fiori tile is to point to the Compopent.js file. So the index.html is not called. The FioriLaunchpad.html plays the role of the index.html and the ComponentContainer is defined there.

Try to register your custom control somewhere else within the app.

Comment: can i register my custom control in component.js?  I' new in ui5

Comment: To register a path you can do:
´sap.ui.getCore().loadLibrary("library.name.space", "/path/to/library");´
in init event of the Component.js file.

I guess you can also register your path as well in the Component.js as in JQuery
jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("library.name.space", "/path/to/library");

Besides, you can add it as a dependency in the manifest.json
´dependencies: {
    libs: ["sap.m", "library.name.space"]
}´

Take a look in the [Demokit](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f23a736f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html)

Comment: [fioriSandbox.html] Failed to load U5 component for navigation intent #Test-url - Error: failed to load 'sap/ui/codetools/CodeEditor.js' from sap/ui/codetools/CodeEditor.js: 404 - Not Found sap.ushell.renderers.fiori2.Shell.controller

Comment: on localhost it runs fine byregistring in component.js file.. whereas on launchpad still error..

Comment: Did you register a relative path? Relative to what? Probably relative to the index.html location??
Could you try an absolute path to your JS file?

Comment: jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("sap.ui.codetools", "sap/ui/codetools/");  this is the way i'm doing right now..

Comment: fioriSandbox.html] Failed to load UI5 component with properties '{"componentData":{"startupParameters":{}},"asyncHints":{"waitFor":[{}]},"name":"myappAutomationRule","url":"../../../../../webapp","async":true,"id":"application-Test-url-component"}'. - Error: failed to load 'sap/ui/codetools/CodeEditor.js' from sap/ui/codetools/CodeEditor.js: 404 - Not Found
    at p1 (https://webidetesting1228513-d065582trial.dispatcher.hanatrial.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:174:7227)

Answer (score -2):

Activate the APP Node on SICF( node Name is same as App)

Comment: Hi Mostafa, when you're answering a question, it's usually helpful to provide an explanation as to why your answer solves the problem and steps to implement your solution. As an example, see the accepted answer from `Nafees Abbasi` which provides an explanation of what is causing the issue as well as the steps to resolve it.