# Is it possible to test Standard SAP Fiori apps from Web IDE?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have imported Standard SAP Fiori apps like HCM_PEP_PROFILE and HCM_LRQ_CRE in Web IDE (not creating an extension project for them)

I run these apps as 'SAP Fiori Launchpad Sandbox' and choose the Component.js file to be run. But I was unable to run these apps.
I tried to replace the standard app's 'neo-app.json'by right-clicking on the project and selecting 'New' > 'HTML5 Application Descriptor'.
This worked for HCM_LRQ_CRE and since the OData service was not on my system, it displayed an error but the rest of the app renders fine.
[image]

But if the do the same for HCM_PEP_PROFILE or a couple of other HCM apps, some other error is displayed and the app does not load at all
[image]

Is it not possible to run some of these apps from Web IDE?
Please help.

Comment: Please look in your browser console and identify what is not being found (Chrome = F12 and then go to the Network tab)

Comment: Is your OData service available from within your WebIDE environment?

Comment: Please check your console log. 
There it should say which component is failing to load.

Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558379/failed-to-load-ui5-component-with-properties-fiori-launchpad
a similar problem was answered like this:
“The common configuration for a Fiori tile is to point to the Component.js file. So the index.html is not called. The FioriLaunchpad.html plays the role of the index.html and the ComponentContainer is defined there. So register your path in the Component.js file. in this way you can fix your problem "